# How to fix 'TxExecutionError' for partial unstake of near coins

Tags: python, rpc, nearprotocol

I am trying using the 'near-api-py' library of the function_call method of the Account class, to unstake my near coins from the staking:

```
from near_api.providers import JsonProvider
from near_api.account import Account
from near_api.signer import KeyPair, Signer
rpc_url = "https://rpc.mainnet.near.org"
near_provider = JsonProvider(rpc_url)
key_pair = KeyPair(private_key)
allnodes_validator_id = 'allnodes.poolv1.near'
_signer = Signer(wallet_id, key_pair)
_account = Account(wallet_id, near_provider, _signer)


def unstake_pool():
        method = 'unstake'
        amount_to_unstake = 1 * NEAR
        tx = _account.function_call(contract_id=allnodes_validator_id,
                                    method_name=method,
                                    args={},
                                    amount=amount_to_unstake)
        print(tx)
        return tx
```

but I get an error:

```
near_api.providers.JsonProviderError: {'name': 'HANDLER_ERROR', 'cause': {'info': {}, 'name': 'INVALID_TRANSACTION'}, 'code': -32000, 'message': 'Server error', 'data': {'TxExecutionError': {'InvalidTxError': {'NotEnoughBalance': {'balance': '594751191937359500000001', 'cost': '1019297408483583729293948', 'signer_id': 'my_wallet_id'}}}}}
```

when using the 'unstake_all' method, everything works. but what if I don't want to take everything off the stakeout?

what am I doing wrong and how do I solve it? thanks

I tried to find a solution in the documentation, but I didn't find it

Comment: `{'NotEnoughBalance': {'balance': '594751191937359500000001', 'cost': '1019297408483583729293948', 'signer_id': 'efe6e8a8f9bc098a672dcfe252a42666dfea38562cf627e5ff8a938c7b.near'}}`
This part of the error says the signer account (provided) doesn't have enough balance to execute the transaction. I believe the easiest way is to throw a couple of NEARs to the account

Comment: manually, an amount of 1 near is available to me to withdraw from the staking. there are no problems when using the 'unstake_all' method. but what if I want to withdraw a partial amount?